# Firestore document listener doesn't return current value from server

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a document snapshot listener for Firebase Firestore. I want to perform some action based on the current document value from the server, but also listen for changes to the document and enable offline cache when possible.

The listener works to update a state when the document changes, but for some reason always operates form a previous cache of what changed when it was listening:

```
let unsub = firebase.firestore().collection('myCol').doc('myDoc').onSnapshot((doc) => {
    if(doc.data().myVal) myFunction(); //myVal is always what the last listener thought it was, not updated from current server value
}
```

So if I then call `unsub()` and make a change to the document in the console, next time the listener is started up, it returns the last cache value from when it was previously listening instead of the first load being from the server.

How can I force the listener to get the first value from the server instead of it's old local cache?

Comment: Can you please try `.onSnapshot({ includeQueryMetadataChanges: true }, (doc) => {})` and check if the source of data is cache by logging ` snapshot.metadata.fromCache`?

Comment: `snapshot.metadata.fromCache` logged as true, adding the metadata changes didn't seem to help

Comment: Have you enabled offline persistence?

Comment: Yes, using `firebase.firestore().enablePersistence().catch((e) => {});`

Comment: The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data) says, "if you have enabled offline persistence, your listeners will receive listen events when the locally cached data changes."

Comment: Yes, I'm aware the listener is getting the data from the local cache. I'm also aware the local cache isn't updating when the listener isn't registered. That is why my question is "How can I force the listener to get from the server first?"

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found a work around @Dharmaraj

Comment: @Mr.Drew Does this not mean that your device is somehow offline? Otherwise, the default is to fetch from server first and then fallback to local cache.

Comment: No, other network calls were working as intended at the time I was experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can currently force the listener logic to load from the server first is by manually triggering a get() on the document first. This simply updates the local cache of any changes that happened when the listener wasn't listening last.

If you're having similar issues with your code, add this before setting the listener logic:

```
await firebase.firestore().collection('myCol').doc('myDoc').get({source: 'server'}).catch(e => {});
```